# The Sum of $\frac 1{n+k}$ and $1+\frac 2{(3k)^3-3k}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, euler-mascheroni-constant

It is easily checked that, for each positive integer $k$,$$\frac 1{3k-1}+\frac 1{3k}+\frac 1{3k+1}=\frac 1k+\frac 2{(3k)^3-3k}\tag1$$Set $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ in $(1)$ and add the $n$ equalities to find that$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^{3n+1}\frac 1k=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac 1k+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac 2{(3k)^3-3k}$$i.e$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2m+1}\frac 1{m+k}=1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\frac 2{(3k)^3-3k}\tag2$$The first three cases, $m=1,2,3,$ of $(2)$ are, respectively,$$\begin{align*}\frac 12+\frac 13+\frac 14 & =1+\frac 2{3^3-3}\\\frac 15+\frac 16+\cdots+\frac 1{13} & =1+\frac 2{3^3-3}+\frac 2{6^3-6}+\frac 2{9^3-9}+\frac 2{12^3-12}\\\frac 14+\frac 1{15}+\cdots+\frac 1{40} & =1+\frac 2{3^3-3}+\cdots+\frac 2{39^3-39}\end{align*}$$More generally, taking $m=1,2,\ldots,n$ in $(2)$ and adding the $n$ equalities, we find that$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{(3^n-1)/2}\frac 1k=n+(n-1)\frac 2{3^3-3}+(n-2)\left(\frac 2{6^3-6}+\frac 2{9^3-9}+\frac 2{12^3-12}\right)+(n-3)\left(\frac 2{15^3-15}+\frac 2{18^3-18}+\cdots+\frac 2{39^3-39}\right)\tag3$$where there are $n$ expressions on the right-hand side of $(3)$.

---

> **Questions:**

1. How does setting $m=1,2,3$ into $(2)$ give the next three equations? I'm getting$$\begin{align*}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{3}\frac 1{k+1} & =\frac 12+\frac 13+\frac 14=1+\frac 2{(3k)^3-3k}\\\sum\limits_{k=1}^{5}\frac 1{k+2} & =\frac 13+\frac 14+\frac 15+\frac 16+\frac 17=1+\frac 2{3^3-3}+\frac 2{6^3-6}\\\sum\limits_{k=1}^7\frac 1{k+3} & =\frac 14+\frac 15+\cdots+\frac 1{10}=1+\frac 2{3^3-3}+\frac 2{6^3-6}+\frac 2{9^3-9}\end{align*}$$
2. If $(2)$ is wrong, does that mean that the final equation $(3)$ is also wrong?
3. How do you arrive at $(3)$?

---

I feel like the PDF is wrong. Whatever value of $m$ you set, the denominator of $1/(m+k)$ will always increase by one. So the third equation cannot exist. I also tried just ignoring the setting $m=1,2,3$ portion and just tried summing both sides for $1\leq m\leq n$ to get$$\sum\limits_{m=1}^n\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2m+1}\frac 1{m+k}=m+2\sum\limits_{m=1}^n\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2m+1}\frac 1{(3k)^3-3k}\tag4$$But I have never dealt with "nested summations" so far. Any tips on simplifying $(4)$?

Comment: Is it $(3k)^3-3k$ instead of $(3k)^3-2k$ in the RHS of (1)?

Comment: Sorry but the whole question is a mess. What is your source?

Comment: Should every $n$ read $m$ in (2)?

Comment: Re the revised version: Some identities are wrong, for example, it seems that $$\frac 14+\frac 1{15}+\cdots+\frac 1{40}$$ should read $$\frac1{14}+\frac 1{15}+\cdots+\frac 1{40}$$ Next, it seems you want to concatenate sums $$\sum_{k=m+1}^{3m+1}$$ thus you do not add (2) "taking $m=1,2,\ldots,n$" but rather, taking $$m=\tfrac12(3^i-1)\qquad 1\leqslant i\leqslant n-1$$ You might try to write down the correct (4) all this is giving you...

Comment: @Did I'm still having trouble understanding $(3)$ for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

Starting with

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2m+1}\frac 1{m+k}=1+2\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\frac 1{(3k)^3-3k}$$

We first set $n=1$ in $\tfrac 12\left(3^n-1\right)$ so $m=1$ to get$$1+\frac 2{3^3-3}=\frac 12+\frac 13+\frac 14$$

Next, if we set $n=2$ so that $m=4$, then we see that

$$1+\frac 2{3^3-3}+\frac 2{6^3-6}+\cdots+\frac 2{12^3-12}=\frac 15+\frac 16+\cdots+\frac 1{13}$$

And when we set $n=3$ so that $m=13$, then

$$1+\frac 2{3^3-3}+\frac 2{6^3-6}+\cdots+\frac 2{39^3-39}=\frac 1{14}+\frac 1{15}+\cdots+\frac 1{40}$$

Now summing every value of $\tfrac 12\left(3^i-1\right)$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1$ and replacing $i$ with $n$ gives us

$$\begin{multline}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left(3^n-1\right)/2}\frac 1k=n+(n-1)\frac 2{3^3-3}+(n-2)\left(\frac 2{6^3-6}+\cdots+\frac 2{12^3-12}\right)+\\(n-3)\left(\frac 2{15^3-15}+\cdots+\frac 2{39^3-39}\right)+\cdots\end{multline}$$

Which is the identity you wish to prove. Now, if you take the limit as $n\to\infty$, then the left-hand side can be rewritten as

$$\begin{align*}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left(3^n-1\right)/2}\frac 1k & =\log\left(\frac {3^n-1}2\right)+\gamma+\omicron(1)\\ & =n\log 3-\log 2+\gamma+\omicron(1)\end{align*}$$

Of which you get a rather interesting identity for $\gamma$ which converges much faster than the basic definition we are probably first introduced to

$$\begin{align*}\gamma & =\log 2-\frac 2{3^3-3}-4\left(\frac 1{6^3-6}+\frac 1{9^3-9}+\frac 1{12^3-12}\right)-\cdots\end{align*}$$